# Не отображается placeholder на select2

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, select2

Вот пример как инициализируется плагин

```js
$(".select_3_wrapp select").select2({
  "width": "100%",
  minimumResultsForSearch: 1,
  placeholder: $(this).attr("data-placeholder")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select_3_wrapp">
  <select data-placeholder="Введите город">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Почему не отображается placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

Для отображение `placeholder` нужно добавить первым пустой `option`, и

```js
$(".select_3_wrapp select").select2({
  "width": "100%",
  minimumResultsForSearch: 1,
    placeholder:  'Введите город'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="select_3_wrapp">
  <select class="js-states form-control">
    <option></option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

[How to use placeholder as default value in select2 framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413241/how-to-use-placeholder-as-default-value-in-select2-framework)